# Метод выполняется два раза, если я редактирую юнита второй раз?

Tags: c#, winforms

Это код в котором я редактирую юнитов, почему-то если я изменил первый раз юнита, то он сохраняется правильно, а если второй раз меняю, то messagebox вылазит второй раз и метод EditM повторяется и соответственно юнит сохраняется второй раз?

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userId = this.dgvStudents.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex + 1;
        user = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
        
        EditForm.StudentUpdated += EditM;
    
        string[] arrFaculties = new string[9];
    
        arrFaculties = client.ShowFaculties(ConvertToUsersArr());
    
        EditForm editForm = new EditForm(client, user, arrFaculties);
        if (editForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
    
        }
        lblUpdate.Visible = true;
    }
    
    
    private void EditM(ServerUser user, ServerUser newUser)
    {
        _users.Remove(user);
        _users.Add(client.Save(user.Id - 1, newUser.Name, newUser.SecondName, newUser.NameOfFamily, newUser.Faculty, newUser.Age, newUser.Course));
        MessageBox.Show($"student with name {user.Name.ToString()} edited");
        
    }
```

А это форма в которой я редактирую юнитов:

```
public partial class EditForm : Form
{

    public delegate void WithParams(ServerUser su, ServerUser newUser);
    ServerUser _user;
    AppServiceClient _client;
    public static event WithParams StudentUpdated;
    string[] _faculties;

    public EditForm(AppServiceClient client, ServerUser serU, string[] faculties)
    {
        _faculties = faculties;
        _user = serU;
        _client = client;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EditForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbId3.Text = _user.Id.ToString();
        tbName3.Text = _user.Name;
        tbSecName3.Text = _user.SecondName;
        tbNameOfFam3.Text = _user.NameOfFamily;
        cmbFac.DataSource = _faculties;
        cmbFac.SelectedItem = _user.Faculty;
        tbCourse3.Text = _user.Course.ToString();
        tbAge3.Text = _user.Age.ToString();
    }
    ServerUser newUser;
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newUser = new ServerUser();
        newUser.Name = tbName3.Text;
        newUser.SecondName = tbSecName3.Text;
        newUser.NameOfFamily = tbNameOfFam3.Text;
        newUser.Faculty = cmbFac.SelectedItem.ToString();
        newUser.Age = int.Parse(tbAge3.Text);
        newUser.Course = int.Parse(tbCourse3.Text);
        StudentUpdated.Invoke(_user, newUser);
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Подскажите что это может быть?

Comment: тебе нужно посмотреть в стек обоих вызовов. Так ты поймешь почему выполняется 2 раза. Или же можешь поставить брейкпоинт на самом методе и дальше кликать Ф11 пока не поймешь почему второй раз вызывается. Короче говоря - учимся дебажить свой код.

Comment: я ставлю точки останова, не помогает, всё выполняется так же, если редактирую юзера первый раз, то метод выполняется один раз, но если начинаю редактировать дальше этого юзера или другого юзера, то метод выполняется два раза, я даже уже return писал в конце метода, не помогает.. метод всё-равно выполняется два раза

Comment: Вы при каждом клике `btnEdit_Click` подписываетесь на событие `EditForm.StudentUpdated += EditM` и не разу не отписываетесь. Сколько раз нажмете столько раз и подпишитесь, следовательно столько раз будет вызван обработчик. Где то после окончания редактирования отпишитесь от события `EditForm.StudentUpdated -= EditM`

Comment: @PavelPopov это можно как ответ оформить, а не как комментарий.

Comment: Pavel Popov, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Andrew да я знаю, просто по хорошему это 100% дубликат вопроса, лень искать аналог )

Answer (score 2):

При каждом клике `btnEdit_Click` вы подписываетесь на событие `EditForm.StudentUpdated += EditM` и ни разу не отписываетесь. Сколько раз нажмете, столько раз и подпишитесь, следовательно столько раз будет вызван обработчик.
Где то после окончания редактирования отпишитесь от события `EditForm.StudentUpdated -= EditM`